# String from Boolean

Tags: c#

How do I make a string such as "You did it!" appear from a boolean pass/fail instead of just "True" or "False"? I'm only ever able to find the ToString method, but all that does is change "True" to "true". I want to know how to make the string output whatever I want.

Comment: I'm  not completely sure, but do you want something like `string s = boolValue ? "It is True" : "It is False";`?

Comment: Why cant you use a simple IF Statement. If it returns a "True" then show one phrase, false gets another. Looks like Jonesopolis beat me to the answer.

Comment: I just wanted to say AdmiralCuddles thank you for posting a good beginner level question. Many new users complain that they are being down voted for asking lower level questions, but the response to this question shows that the real issue is that they are asking bad questions. Keep it up and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 7):

A `bool` is a type, the same way a `string` is a type.  You'll never be able to get a bool type to show "You did it!", because its a bool - it can only be true or false.

What you want is to create a string based on the result of boolean.  Sounds like you want an `if` statement:

```
string myString;
if(myBool) // if true
{
    myString = "You did it!";
}
else
{
    myString = "You didn't do it";
}
```

like @juharr showed, there are ways to do this in less lines of code, but this is the logic that needs to happen.

As a side note, you see the `ToString` method on `bool` because every type inheriting from `System.Object` inherits the `ToString` method, providing you with a string representation of that object.  It's not applicable for what you're wanting to accomplish here.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the default implementation of `ToString()` is the fully qualified type name, unless the type has overridden the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# 3.0 or higher, you can also put this in an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for *bool* like this:

```
public static string ToDidItOrNotString(this bool b)
{
    return b ? "You did it!" : "You did not do it.";
}
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
string s = boolVal.ToDidItOrNotString();
```

Comment: Unless this was needed in many parts of the application, I would not create an extension method for it.   It would strike me as overkill.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

To display the string in your view when using data binding you can use a custom IValueConverter:

```
public class BoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string TrueString { get; set; }
    public string FalseString { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValue = (bool)value;

        return boolValue ? TrueString : FalseString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<stackOverflow:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BoolToStringConverter" TrueString="You did it!" FalseString="You didn't do it"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding WasItDone, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that creating an `Extension Method` is the closer you can get from what you want.

Create a `BoolExtensions` class:

```
public static class BoolExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this bool boolean, string valueIfTrue, string valueIfFalse)
    {
        return boolean ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var trueBoolean = true;
    Console.WriteLine(trueBoolean.ToString("You did it!", "You didn't do it"));
    var falseBoolean = false;
    Console.WriteLine(falseBoolean.ToString("You did it!", "You didn't do it"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Notice that both the `BoolExtensions` class and it's `ToString` method are marked as `static`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the ToString method of a known type in c#, but you can create extension methods, if you will use this string in many parts of your code you can create a method for this like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToStringCustom(this bool booleanValue)
    {
        if(booleanValue)
          return "You did it";
        else
          return "You didn't do id";
    }
}
```

and then when you use boolean variables this method will be available for you, like:

```
Console.WriteLine(true.ToStringCustom())
```

this will print "You did it".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this functionality in multiple places, you can create an extension method like;

```
public static string YouDidIt(this bool value )
{
    if (value) return "You did it!";

    return "You failed";
}
```

Then you can use it like;

```
bool a = true;
string s = a.YouDidIt();
```